# sending emails in php - answermail

Tags: php, email

I have a problem with sending answer mails ans hope somebody can help me. First of all, sorry for my english ;)

I'm programming a forum. By sending an e-mail, datas (id, message, sender-mail, receiver-mails) get entered into a database. In the mail, there is also a link to a php-site. On this site one can accept/cancel (via checkboxes) and these commitments/cancellations will be sent in an answer-mail to the original sender of the mail.

Now my problem: I'm not able to send the answer-mail automatically back to the original sender, because I don't know how to get the mail-address.

Is there a possibility to include the ID in the mail, so that I'm able to filer the mail-address from the database?
Or are there any other possibilities?

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't very clear but I'll try anyway. If what you're trying to do is to know which recipient clicked a link in your email you can add that email plus a unique hash key to ensure authenticity of that info.

For example if email is abc@example.com then you could add the email as a parameter plus a hash parameter that it a simple hash of the email and a salt string to verify it was actually from the email sent to that person.

This is simpler than keeping it all in the database but you can also decide to store all pending confirmations for some days so that even a hacker won't be able to guess email addresses.